# Something bugging me about Facebook Timer

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, timer

If you have used Facebook, you might have the noticed there is a timer in everything that appears on the page, which are constantly updating in minutes. Which, I am wondering is not affecting the performance of the website.

Whether It is a Ajax Request triggered by a timer or Just plain client side Timer, the point is a lot of timers are used. Wont using a lot timers like this affect the site's performance? or There is something I am missing.

Comment: @mu, I dont think batch would be a good idea, because what if at the first batch, there had to be 100 AJAX calls or more. that would definately slow the site. I think there has to be individual timers assigned to every post. What is the strange thing is that? Using so my timers is not degrading the site, performance wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only takes one timer to do what Facebook is doing. Each time it fires, it iterates over all `abbr` elements with `class="timestamp` and calculates an update based on the custom `data-date` attribute they've defined.

Comment: In other words, the absolute time of each timestamp is stored in the DOM and then each time it runs, the script calculates the difference between that time and the current local time.  No AJAX requests necessary.

Comment: Thus offloading all of the processing to the client-side.

Comment: Can you setup a demonstration to show what you are stating? But if you have noticed, each post changes the time individually not all post at a time. How does one `setInterval()` fire on different intervals.

Comment: Well I think you are right, I notice facebook timer very closely today and it seems every time are updated at once

Answer (score 0):

Sure, anything you add that runs a `setInterval()` will change the performance of a website.

However, unless Facebook shows time down to the second, it probably runs once a minute.

I've also noticed Facebook uses lot of fuzzy times, like *just then*, etc. This may mean the `setInterval()` runs on an even longer interval.

Comment: Well, that's my actual confusion, when so many setInterval() are running together, how does facebook performs so smoothly?